# mesa update breaks build

Tags: opengl, mesa

Today a new mesa has been released on ubuntu 16.04.02 https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 However it breaks my build, when I link my lib to libGL.so

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: undefined reference to `drmFreeDevice'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: undefined reference to `drmGetDevices'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: undefined reference to `drmGetDevice'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: undefined reference to `drmFreeDevices'
```

Downgrading to the previous versions manually fixes my issue. Does someone else have this issue? Any idea to fix it cleanly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone ever has this issue, I solved it by linking to libdrm in my application.